# l3kernel could not be found

Tags: expl3, latex3

I was hoping to use packages which uses LaTeX3e, so I did the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{l3kernel}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

where I have got this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `l3kernel.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
```

I suspect if my installation did wrong at some point, meanwhile I am using

- TeX Live 2016 (portable)
- Windows 7
- TeX Studio portable, the version downloaded last month.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK, there is no such LaTeX package `l3kernel.sty` for use in `\usepackage`.
But there is a CTAN/TeX distribution package "l3kernel", bundling LaTeX packages like `expl3.sty`, `l3*.sty` packages and a class `l3doc.cls`.

Comment: How should I call the packages then?

Comment: @SHY.John I have no idea, what you want to do. If you want to use a package, which requires LaTeX3, then just load the package. An example is `siunitx`, which uses `expl3`, `xparse`, and `l3keys2e`. But the user just loads it by `\usepackage{siunitx}`.

Comment: Emm... I've loaded `siunitx` at first.

Comment: @SHY.John And ...?

Comment: @cfr I have loaded `siunitx` then `l3kernel` and here comes the error messages.

Comment: @SHY.John Why do you want to load `l3kernel`? Package `siunitx` already loads the packages, which it needs.

Comment: @heiko-oberdiek It was my fault, since I want to use packages that can typeset chemical species which require LaTeX 3. While I wasn't aware that `siunitx` has already done the job.